# Boostrap datepicker does not display years with min date and yearRange options

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I want run Boostrap datepicker with mindate and year range but there is a problem with these options.When run the following code year range not display.

How to solve this?

```
 $(datePiker).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    yearRange: "-100:-13",
                    defaultDate: "-13y",
                    minDate: 5,
                });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set exactly yearRange and defaultDate then solved.

```
$(datePiker).datepicker({
                dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: "2000/01/01:2010/01/01",
                defaultDate: "2000/01/01",
                minDate: 5,
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I think there is a problem with the `dateFormat`. Also, instead of `minDate` use `startDate`

See this [website](https://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox), it may help you.